# I'm getting this error: filter object at 0x041A7F28 error when I run this program listed below

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to get this program to print the verbs, I get the same error in the interpreter and as a program ran from the command line.  Any help would be great! Thank you in advance!

```
  from __future__ import print_function
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

with open ('words.txt') as fin
    for line in fin:

        tokens = word_tokenize(line)

pos_tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)

print(pos_tagged)

verbs = filter(lambda x:x[1]=='VB',pos_tagged)

print(verbs)
```

output:

```
[('German', 'JJ'),... ('has', 'VBZ'), ('shown.3', 'VBN')]
```

error: `<filter object at 0x041A7F28>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<filter object at 0x041A7F28>
```

That's not an error.  That's how filter objects print.

To get the *results* of the filter, you have to iterate over the filter object.  The easiest way to do that is to pass it to `list()`:

```
verbs = list(filter(lambda x:x[1]=='VB',pos_tagged))
```